# list object not callable calling a function whose parameter is also a function with an array

Tags: python, benchmarking

Please can you help with the follwing?

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/isabella/Desktop/GMIT/Algorithms/CTA_Project/main.py", line 186, in <module>
    timeAlgo(insertionSort(arr))
  File "/Users/isabella/Desktop/GMIT/Algorithms/CTA_Project/main.py", line 179, in timeAlgo
    algo()
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

```
# Implementation of Insertion Sort algorithm | Ref: [1]
def insertionSort(arr):
    
    # Iterates over elements in the given arr starting at index 2
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        
        while arr[i - 1] > arr[i] and i > 0:
            arr[i - 1], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[i - 1]
            i -= 1  # Moves down one index
    
    return arr

# Times algorithm
def timeAlgo(algo):
    # Starts timing
    start = time.time()
    # Executes algorithm
    algo()
    # Ends timing
    end = time.time()
    totalTime = end - start
    return totalTime

arr = genRandomArr()
timeAlgo(insertionSort(arr))
```

Comment: "line 179"? There aren't nearly that many lines here.

Comment: Yes, well I have some more algorithms in functions. I didnt need to copy them all here

Comment: But you could tell us which line it is.

Comment: Or if you had provided the [mre] then the line number would be right.

Comment: Exactly, I should've provided the line number but I also don't think it's too difficult to see where the problem is based on the keywords in the error message ie., timeAlgo(insertionSort(arr)) & timeAlgo algo()...

Comment: Ah, right, I managed to overlook it. Probably because I'm used to tracebacks being shown properly formatted.

Comment: Any more critiques? They're most welcome

Comment: who is isabella ?

Comment: where your CTA_projects stands in https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/CTA ?

Comment: does it work on > 1D arrays ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import time

def insertionSort(arr):
    
    # Iterates over elements in the given arr starting at index 2
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        
        while arr[i - 1] > arr[i] and i > 0:
            arr[i - 1], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[i - 1]
            i -= 1  # Moves down one index
    
    return arr


def timeAlgo(algo, *args):
    # Starts timing
    start = time.time()
    # Executes algorithm
    algo(*args)
    # Ends timing
    end = time.time()
    totalTime = end - start
    return totalTime

arr = [2,4,6,1,0]
timeAlgo(insertionSort, arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the function that mesures the execution time as a decorator

```py
from functools import wraps
import time


def timeAlgo(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args):
        start = time.time()
        res = func(*args)
        end = time.time()
        print(f'{end - start} seconds')
        return res

    return wrapper


@timeAlgo
def insertionSort(arr):
    
    # Iterates over elements in the given arr starting at index 2
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        
        while arr[i - 1] > arr[i] and i > 0:
            arr[i - 1], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[i - 1]
            i -= 1  # Moves down one index
    
    return arr

print(insertionSort([2,4,6,1,0]))
```

Comment: This is the error I get: 
TypeError: insertionSort() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arr'

Comment: the call `algo()` should be `algo(arr)`

Answer (score 0):

Just properly defer the execution:

```
timeAlgo(lambda: insertionSort(arr))
```